# Excel how to define Worksheetfunction as a "global" object so any function can access it by a simple alias

Tags: excel, vba

Currently whenever I want to call a worksheetfunction inside a function, e.g. `LN, NORMDIST` I'll have to write something like

```vb
    Function f()
    Dim wsf 
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    'only then can I call them by wsf.func, like
    Dim v
    v = wsf.Ln(2.0)   'Natural log of 2
    f = v
    End Function
```

This looks tedious. Is there a way to define the `WorksheetFunction` object globally or module-wide, so that any function inside this module can call it directly?

(To be honest, I find the whole idea of having to access lots of builtin functions via the `WorksheetFunction` object really annoying)

Comment: All those lines can be simplified to `f = WorksheetFunction.Ln(2)`. Or you can use `f = Application.Ln(2)`.

Comment: @BigBen this is just a toy example. My situation is that there are a lot of built-in funcs like `Ln`, `NormDist` etc I need to call inside my function, which is far more complicated than the example I show here.

Comment: Then use a `With WorksheetFunction...End With` block. But if you can simplify your example, boiling it down to that one-liner, I'm assuming you can similarly simplify your real code.

Comment: The functionality you seek is available in Dot Net. 

Instead of writing `X.Blah1` or `X.Blah2`, you declare `Imports/using X` at the top. This way when you use an object of the given namespace in a Module/ Class, you are saying that **If I am using `Blah1` or `Blah2` then it is from X**.

Unfortunately that functionality is not present in VBA. Having said that, you can create your own dll with preferred functions and then call them but then that is a tedious process.

Comment: One other thing, what you want can create a **chaos** in VBE. VBE doesn't have something, which us humans have.. **FREEWILL.**

Till the time you are using functions which are not common to Worksheet Function for example `Sum`, `Average` etc, then it would work fine but functions like `Mid` can create a problem.

In a VBA, when you you use the statement "Mid" then which library should VBA refer to. The AI is not that advanced as to you can leave the choice on it. It doesn't have FreeWill **Hey VBA, choose an option from "Option A" or "Option B". Note that both do the same thing.** :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout It's not that I want to directly access the functions like `from xxx import *` in python. What I want is more like `import xxx as alias` then call `alias.f()` so I don't have to write the long name of `xxx` every time I do so. As suggested in other comments and the accepted answer, a `With` block may be the easiest workaround, though not equivalent to `import`.

Comment: I posted the comments because you had unaccepted the answer :D If you are happy with the `With End With` (which is the normal way of handling these kind of situations) then all is good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a strange thing to do (i.e. a `With … EndWith` block would be the usual way of calling multiple functions without repeating the keyword).

Theoretically, though, it could be done like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private wsf As WorksheetFunction

Public Sub Test()       
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Debug.Print wsf.Sum(1, 2, 3)
    Debug.Print wsf.Average(1, 2, 3)        
End Sub
```